# Laravel 5 - How Do You Catch an Mail::send() Error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I have the following method which sends out an e-mail:

```
Mail::send('emails.configuration_test', array(), function($email)use($request){
    $email->to($request->test_address)->subject('Configuration Test');
});
```

If the above errors out, I'd like to be able to catch the exception.  When I use the following:

```
try{
    Mail::send('emails.configuration_test', array(), function($email)use($request){
        $email->to($request->test_address)->subject('Configuration Test');
    });
}
catch(Exception $e){
    // Never reached
}
```

the exception is never caught.  Instead I get a Laravel stacktrace as the response if the `send()` method errors out.

How do I catch the exception in this case?

Comment: If the file is namespaced, you'll need to `catch(\Exception $e)` (or put `use Exception` at the top of the file). Right now, it's probably catching something like `App\Http\Controllers\Exception`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Or import it at the top. Which I assume he has.

Comment: @devk If he's getting a stacktrace after `catch(Exception $e)` he hasn't.

Comment: @ceejayoz Fair enough. I thought you get the Laravel exception message.

Comment: @devk All Laravel exceptions are eventually subclasses (or sub-sub-sub-subclasses) of the root `\Exception`, so catching `\Exception` should cover literally everything if done correctly.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Using the root namespace `\Exception` did the trick.

Instead of:

```
catch(Exception $e){
    // Never reached
}
```

I used:

```
catch(\Exception $e){
    // Get error here
}
```

Comment: Is this really a good way to use exceptions?  Couldn't we create a more specific exception for a mail send error and catch that?  I was searching the framework for such an exception to catch, but couldn't find one :(   I suppose the main goal here is to let the code continue if a mail fails to send rather than stop executing and abort. But the catch of the universal exception doesn't express that intention very clearly. Just my take on it.

Comment: Have realised the key point here is that laravel uses Symfony swift mailer, so simply need to look at the docs for that, not laravel.

Comment: Generally to find a specific exception get_class() can be used, like this: `catch (\Exception $e){ dd(get_class($e)); }` . Then use the output like this: `catch (\Swift_TransportException $e){...`