# Laravel 5.5 - Mailgun catch email errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am sending email via Mailgun from a Laravel 5.5 app like this...

```
    Mail::send('emails.sendmessage', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
        $message->to($data['email']);
        $message->from('me@example.com.com', 'Ueer');
        $message->subject('Sample Email');
    });

    /* Return Success Response */
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'status_code' => 200,
        'response' => 'success',
    ));
```

How can I catch Mailgun errors with this code?  Sometimes MailGun returns an error message and I would like to return a different response if this happens

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at this question : [Laravel 5 - How Do You Catch an Mail::send() Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513882/laravel-5-how-do-you-catch-an-mailsend-error)

Adding a try and catch should do the trick.

If you don't want to add a try/catch for whatever reason, I would recommend you to validate beforehand every parameters susceptile of throwing an error from Mail::send

Comment: When I added a backslash to my try-catch construct, then I could handle the error:`try{ ... } catch (\Exception $e) { ... }`